# What are the capabilites of global-scaled magnetic field alteration technology?

Tags: electromagnetism

Once you have technology to alter the Earths magnetic fields , how far is that from magnetic space fields propelling vehicles?

Comment: Its a little more like that _2020_2020_2020_2020_2020_2020_2020_2020_2020_2020_2020_2020 vision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more like science fiction rather than science.

The earths magnetic field is too weak for it to be good enough for anything other than discovering the constitution of the interior of the earth and setting compasses by.

Answer (score 0):

How far is that? As far as possible i.e., the distance from nothing to nowhere. Those two things have nothing to do with each other except that they are both impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that there are trains that use magnetic levitation and magnetic propulsion.  That would involve adding stronger varying local fields to the pre-existing weak magnetic field from the earth.